# unit sphere is weak dense in the unit ball

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, reference-request

As I remember the following is true:

**Fact:** *for every infinite-dimensional normed space $X$ 
the unit sphere $S$ is weak-dense in the unit ball $B$.*

Please help me find a reference.

Thanks in advance

Miki

Comment: Since this is a common homework problem in beginning courses, I will not answer unless you identify yourself.

Comment: Why do you need a reference for this if you have a proof?  I do not think it is the kind of thing you have to cite a reference for...

Answer (score 2):

Right, I just want to have a **reference**.

As to the proof. One of them is:

Let $a \in B$. Consider a typical weak-nbd $V$ of $a$ in $X$ parameterized by the functionals $f_i \in X^*$, $i=1,2,\cdots,n$ and $\varepsilon >0$.
Use the following function $\alpha: K \to R, \alpha(x)=||a+x||$, where $K=\cap^n_i ker(f_i)$.

Since $K$ is not 0-dimensional (here we need the assumption that $X$ is infinite-dimensional)
we get by intermediate value theorem that $||a+x_0||=1$ for some $x_0 \in K$. This means that $V \cap S$ is non-empty.

Thanks in advance for your information about a reference.

Miki

Comment: I rather strongly suspect that a reference might be hard to find, given that this is so very elementary and well known.

Answer (score 2):

It's exercise V.1.10 in J. Conway, *A Course in Functional Analysis, 2e*, if that's any help.